# Return Set of subtype

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

Assuming I have a data type defined as

```
data Foo = Hello Int | World Int
```

and functions as

```
isWorld :: Foo -> Bool
isWorld (World i) = True
isWorld (Hello i) = False

getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set World
getWorlds = Set.filter isWorld
```

This does not work:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `World'
```

This makes sense as `World` is just a function, but I have no idea how to model this in Haskell. Is using `data` correct? I would like to be able to define functions for certain instances only:

```
foo :: World -> Int
foo (World i) = i
```

As expected, this raises the same error, as `World` is not a type. Is there a way to do this, preferably without GHC extensions?

Comment: `getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set World` has to be `getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set Foo`

Comment: @Redu I know that that will work, but I am looking for an alternative in order to be able to declare functions (e.g. `foo` above) for a subset only.

Comment: You can unwrap the constructor in `getWorlds`: `getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set Int`. But it is not possible (afaik) to restruct the constructors that can be used.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you, I considered that, but I think it will become ugly for more complex data types. I was looking for something like a union type as present in other languages, so I could define `data World = World Int`, `data Hello = Hello Int`, `type Foo = World | Hello`, but I didn't find  an analogy in Haskell.

Comment: @just.me: well you can use `type Foo = Either World Hello`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But that won't let me use the same semantics as `data Foo = ...`, right? And it won't work for types with more than two possible subsets, unless I use it recursively.

Comment: When defining a type, type constructors and value constructors are used. They may have the same name like `data Hello = Hello String Int Hello` (even recursive) however in the type signature you have to express the function's type by using the the type constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to simply make a type for the value of each constructor.

```
newtype Hello = Hello Int deriving (Eq,Ord)
newtype World = World Int deriving (Eq,Ord)
type Foo = Either Hello World

getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set World
getWorlds = Set.fromList . rights . Set.toList       -- import Data.Either
```

Comment: But for more than two types, this will quickly become ugly, right? `type Foo = Either Hello (Either World Bla)`

Comment: You can construct your own thing instead of using `Either` - e.g. `data Foo =   Hello Hello | World World | Bla Bla`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you want to have a list (edit: or rather a set but same logic applies) of two possible things while regular lists in Haskell are homegenous. But if you define your data like so, by wrapping a set of separate types in another data type:

```
newtype Hello = Hello Int
newtype World = World Int
data Foo = FooHello Hello
         | FooWorld World
```

You can still:

- have a list of `Foo`
- filter `Foo` using a function of type `Foo -> Bool` to achieve `f Foo -> f World` (as an example)
- extend Foo to an arbitrary number of constructors as needed

Depending on what you're trying to do there are probably already some libraries that tackle similar issues. I can think of at least [one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-sum) that seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `World` is not a type, it's only a constructor.

The idiomatic solution in Haskell is to use `Either` to create a union of types:

```
newtype Hello = Hello { getHello :: Int } deriving (Ord, Eq)
newtype World = World { getWorld :: Int } deriving (Ord, Eq)
type Foo = Either Hello World

isWorld :: Foo -> Bool
isWorld = Data.Either.isRight

getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set World
getWorlds = Set.fromDistinctAscList . Data.Either.rights . Set.toAscList

foo :: World -> Int
foo = getWorld
```

It works just fine for more than two constructors

```
newtype Cheese = Cheese { getCheese :: Int }
newtype Bread = Bread { getBread :: Int }
newtype Wine = Wine { getWine :: Int }

type Comestible = Either Cheese (Either Bread Wine)
```

but if you find parens distasteful, you can use `Either` infix:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
-- ...
type Comestible = Cheese `Either` Bread `Either` Wine
-- (NOTE: this parses as Either (Either Cheese Bread) Wine
```

and if that's too verbose, you can declare your own operator:

```
type (+) = Either
infixr 5 +
type Comestible = Cheese + Bread + Wine
```

I used `+` here because `Either a b` is a *sum* type, in contrast to `(a,b)` which is a *product* type.

Answer (score 1):

Two more options you could take:

### Keep it simple

and just deal with the *contents* of the individual alternatives. I.e. you could just write

```
getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set Int
getWorlds = Set.mapMonotonic (\(World i)->i) $ Set.filter isWorld
```

### Use only one `data` type...

but restrict which alteratives can be taken through type constraints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

data Foo (a :: FooC) where
  Hello :: CanHello a => Int -> Foo a
  World :: CanWorld a => Int -> Foo a

data FooC = FooC | HelloC | WorldC

class CanHello (a :: FooC)
instance CanHello 'FooC
instance CanHello 'HelloC

class CanWorld (a :: FooC)
instance CanWorld 'FooC
instance CanWorld 'WorldC
```

At this point, you have three different “flavours” of `Foo`:

- `Foo' 'FooC` is like your original type: its value can be either `Hello` or `World`, because `FooC` is an instance of both classes.
- `Foo' 'WorldC` is like what you meant by the `World` type: its constructor `World` is just the same as for `Foo`, but it does not allow the `Hello` constructor.
- `Foo' 'HelloC` *only* allows the `Hello` constructor.

So you can now give them names...

```
type Foo = Foo' 'FooC
type World = Foo' 'WorldC
type Hello = Foo' 'HelloC
```

and then write

```
getWorlds :: Set Foo -> Set World
getWorlds = Set.mapMonotonic (\(World i)->World i) $ Set.filter isWorld
```

The function `\(World i) -> World i` looks superfluous, but is actually necessary: you wrap the data in a new constraint, which actually witnesses that it's always `World`.